# System.ComponentModel.Composition MEF with Open Generics

Tags: c#, .net, mef

I've read lots of information regarding **MEF** and Open generic exports.

There are two versions of **MEF**..

- One Packaged with Framework (System.ComponentModel.Composition.*)
- NuGet Available "MEF v2" which is the portable version

Up to now I've successfully used MEF for a number of extensible apps but this is the first time I've tried to export open generics.

```
[InheritedExport(typeof(IRepository<>))]
public interface IRepository<T> : IRepositoryBase, IDisposable where T : class, IModel, new()
{
    T ById(string id);
}

[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
[InheritedExport(typeof(IRepository<>))]
public class MyRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IModel, new()
{
    // concrete imp............
}
```

Then I want to:

```
var someRepo = _container.GetInstance<IRepository<SomeModel>>();
```

The part is exported, which leads me to think it should be possible.
Not sure if I need to do any explicit mapping (given I'm decorating the interface with `InheritedExport`).

I'm using .NET 4.5.1, and ComponentModel.Composition version of MEF.

Is the open generic functionality only part of the NuGet version of MEF?

I've seen old posts with people using MEF contrib and the pre-shipped version of MEF.. but that seems old now

Any advice welcome.Thanks.

Comment: If anyone has this problem, it's only an issue when `GetInstance` from the composition container.  From an integration unit test, it would appear the open generics import does work when stepping into the `ImportingConstructor`

Comment: [Works for me](https://gist.github.com/binki/f7517e47f03f2810b8ab). However, I don’t know where you get `_container.GetInstance()` from. I only know of [`CompositionContainer.GetExportedValue<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.compositioncontainer.getexportedvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Another thing: MEF from .net-4.0 (“V1” of MEF) doesn’t support automatically closing open types—you need at least .net-4.5.